# Create Google Maps Circle and set its radius in React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

Given the below data:

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Park Slope",
            "latitude": "40.6710729",
            "longitude": "-73.9988001"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bushwick",
            "latitude": "40.6942861",
            "longitude": "-73.9389312"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "East New York",
            "latitude": "40.6577799",
            "longitude": "-73.9147716"
        }
    ]
]
```

I'm creating markers via [react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#introduction) like this:

```
<Map
    center={{ lat: 40.64, lng: -73.96 }}
    zoom={12}
    places={data}
    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="
    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `800px` }} />}
    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  />
```

where

```
class Map extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
      >
        {this.props.places.map(place => {
          return (
            <Marker
              position={{
                lat: parseFloat(place.latitude),
                lng: parseFloat(place.longitude)
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
}
```

Now along with markers I would like to render a **circle** but only for a specific  marker, for example for the first place:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Park Slope",
    "latitude": "40.6710729",
    "longitude": "-73.9988001"
},
```

something like below:

[image]

Is it supported to render and circle via [react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#introduction) and in addition to specify properties such as radius?

Comment: Radius of what? Based on what? How do you want to display the radius? As text? Your question is unclear.

Comment: You still didn't say from where you are getting that radius. I can't see anything in the posted code that looks like a radius (as a distance, in meters, km, or whatever). Anyway, to display a Circle below your marker, you need to create a [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Circle).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since markers properties are passed via `places` prop, one option to consider would be to pass circle properties along with places data, for example:

```
const places = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Park Slope",
    latitude: "40.6710729",
    longitude: "-73.9988001",
    circle: {
      radius: 3000,
      options: {
        strokeColor: "#ff0000"
      }
    }
  },   
  ...
]
```

Then to render markers along with a circles `Map` component could be modified like this:

```
class Map extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
      >
        {this.props.places.map(place => {
          return (
            <Fragment key={place.id}>
              <Marker
                position={{
                  lat: parseFloat(place.latitude),
                  lng: parseFloat(place.longitude)
                }}
              />
              {place.circle && (
                <Circle
                  defaultCenter={{
                    lat: parseFloat(place.latitude),
                    lng: parseFloat(place.longitude)
                  }}
                  radius={place.circle.radius}
                  options={place.circle.options}
                />
              )}
            </Fragment>
          );
        })}
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-p5v8uy)